# Ignore rotation when hitting the extra small breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row, containing 6 `col-md-2`, with each col containing 2 `col-xs-6`, in order to wrap them into two columns when using mobile.
However, when using, lets say, on a PC, my columns have the text rotated. The problem is that I don't want this to happen when hitting the `col-xs`, I want the text to stay horizontal. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Sample html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 skew-text">
    AAAA
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Class:

```
.skew-text {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a media query and only apply your styles when over that breakpoint's screen width:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .skew-text {
        -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

Protip: [You don't need all those vendor prefixes for basic transforms](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d)